# What am I doing wrong in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, exp

I have this problem (first picture) that gets a wrong plot in the red dashed line in the second picture, while it should get the plot with the solid blue line, which is in the third picture, which I got from Chegg.com.

I figured out with some help that 18.7*exp(-0.0193*t) diminishes to nearly 0. Therefore the divisor (1+18.7*exp(-0.0193*t)) will always be practically a value of 1, and P will always be practically 11.5.

Here is my script:

```
x1 = [1850, 1910, 1950, 1980, 2000, 2010];
y1 = [1.3, 1.75, 3, 4.4, 6, 6.8];
x2 = [1900:10:2200];
P = 11.55./(1+18.7*exp(-0.0193*x2))
plot(x1, y1, 'g*', x2, P, '--r')
```

Here's the results of the Command Window:

> P =
>
> Columns 1 through 11
>
> 11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500
>
> Columns 12 through 22
>
> 11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500
>
> Columns 23 through 31
>
> 11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500   11.5500

Problem:

[image]

My plot:

[image: My plot results]

Chegg plot:

[image: Chegg plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text says "t is in years since 1850". So I think you need to do:

```
P = 11.55./(1+18.7*exp(-0.0193* (x2-1850) )
                                 ^^^^^^^
```

You are plotting the tail of the function only, rather than the interesting part.